# How to make a script which create a file with the info i want?

Tags: linux, centos, scripting, programming

i'm a newbie on Linux here and i was hoping to find help. I was using Centos and i've found an exercise where i have to create a script.

This script should create a text file with the network interfaces's info of the machine.
How can i do that?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What is your problem? Do you need help listing the network interfaces? A possible command is `ip link`. Or do you need help redirecting the output of a command to a file? The shell makes this possible with the `>` operator.

Comment: i just need to make a script which will create a file text with my Ip a info in it

Comment: I could hand you such a script, but I work in training and don't believe in providing results to learners. You need to figure this out yourself, and ask specific questions if certain details don't work as expected.

Comment: (1/2) "_i just need to make a script which will create a file text with my Ip a info in it_". Please read what has been written. (1) we could write your script for you, but then it's not you that's written it, which is what you've asked, (2) we can help you break down the problem into small enough parts that you can achieve it yourself. This is what @berndbausch has offered you. Cont'd...

Comment: (2/2) On the other hand, if you meant "_I want someone else to write my script for me_", I doubt you'll get many people helping you. But I'm sure that's not what you meant, so I suggest you [edit] your question to show what you have tried, what you wanted it to do, what it did instead, and what you've tried to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shell output redirection symbols: `>` and `>>`.

- `>` creates a new file or overwrites an existing file.
- `>>` creates a new file or appends to an existing file.

e.g.:

`ls >> lsoutput` creates a file called `lsoutput` in your current working directory with output of the `ls` command.  If `lsoutput` already exist, the `ls` command output will be added to the end of the `lsoutput` file.

Hope this helps.